# SQL query takes 10+ minutes to run, split in two it takes 26 seconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a SQL query to pull manufacturing data and figure out the cost per month compared to output. The query structure is massive (200+ lines over 4 queries). It takes over 5 minutes to run. I don't think I ever actually let it run completely.

The production cost part takes 13 seconds to run. I could not understand how it would take so long to run the rest of the report. So dumped the production cost into a table and ran the sales report using the table. Voila! Now the sales report takes 13 seconds!

Now how can I make my query only take 26 seconds to run?

Here is the line in the sales report query that pulls in the production cost. `[Production Cost Per Job]` is the production cost query.

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        bpc.StartingMonth,  
        bol.[Item No_] as ItemNo, 
        SUM(bpc.Amount) / SUM(bpc.Quantity) as Cost
    FROM "Production Output Line" as bol
    INNER JOIN [Production Cost Per Job] as bpc
        ON bol.[JobID] = bpc.[JobID]
        AND bol."Output Item Size" = bpc.ItemSize
        AND DATEDIFF(mm, 0, bol.[Starting Date]) = bpc.StartingMonth
    WHERE bpc.Quantity <> 0 
    AND bpc.StartingMonth <= a.MonthDate
    AND bpc.StartingMonth >= 1380 -- January 2015
    AND bol.[Item No_] = a.ItemNo
    GROUP BY bpc.StartingMonth, bol.[Item No_]
    ORDER BY bpc.StartingMonth
) as b
```

Comment: being that you are doing an inner join have you tried moving your where logic into your join clause. Sql will evaluate the where clause last and can cause serious degradation of your query. It should be much faster by moving that logic up a level.

Comment: do you mean moving it into the ON?

Comment: yes sorry should have been on clause and not join clause

Comment: Ok, just tried it and it does not make a difference. The problem is more along the lines of it taking massively longer to use the production query than it takes to dump the query to a table and use that.

Comment: Unfortunately without an execution plan or some other type of monitoring data to go off of there is really not much more that I can suggest... Sorry

Comment: The DATEDIFF line gives me the month-year of the line, rather than just the month. Otherwise, I have to do string comparisons and this seems to be faster and is definitely less complicated to write.

Comment: what are your indexes on? Past the execution plan

Comment: I am not familiar with the indexes currently in use. This is a report being built off of an existing system. However, I'm pretty sure I could add indexes.

Comment: What is alias a?

Comment: That is a rather simple union query.

Comment: It has a group by and sum.

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` as your culprit. Avoid using it unless absolutely necessary. In your case it causes your query to be evaluated once for every ItemNo, hence glacially slow performance. See: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Comment: In this case it appears to be absolutely necessary since I need the latest entry before a certain date.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your logic, I think something like the following would work quite effectively (I don't know what you have in `a` so I've just created `a.a_rows` as well as the `MonthDate` field):

```
SELECT
    a_rows
    , MonthDate
    , StartingMonth
    , ItemNo
    , Cost
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a_rows
            , MonthDate
            , StartingMonth
            , ItemNo
            , Cost
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a_rows, MonthDate ORDER BY StartingMonth) R
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    a.a_rows
                    , a.MonthDate
                    , bpc.StartingMonth
                    , bol.[Item No_] ItemNo
                    , SUM(bpc.Amount) / SUM(bpc.Quantity) Cost
                FROM
                    [a] a
                    LEFT JOIN [Production Output Line] bol ON bol.[Item No_] = a.ItemNo
                    LEFT JOIN [Production Cost Per Job] bpc ON
                        bpc.StartingMonth <= a.MonthDate
                        AND bpc.StartingMonth >= 1380
                        AND bpc.Quantity <> 0
                GROUP BY
                    a.a_rows
                    , a.MonthDate
                    , bpc.StartingMonth
                    , bol.[Item No_]
            ) Q
    ) Q2
WHERE R = 1
```